# Parametric recursive looped SQLite insert - do all columns have to be supplied?

Tags: sqlite, insert

I added a new column to my table, so there are now 4 instead of 3, and am now getting the following error when do a parametric insert (looped):

```
table 'test' has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

Does this mean that you have to code your query for EVERY column the table has (as opposed to just the columns you want populated) when doing inserts, and that SQLite won't just add a default value if a column is missing from the query?

My query is:

```
"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test VALUES (NULL, @col2, @col3)"
```

And this is the code that controls what's inserted in the recursive lopp:

```
sqlStatement.clearParameters();     
var _currentRow:Object = _dataArray.shift();
sqlStatement.parameters["@col2"] = _currentRow.val2;
sqlStatement.parameters["@col3"] = _currentRow.val3; 
sqlStatement.execute();
```

Ideally, I'd like column 4 to be left blank, without having to code it into the query.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inserting less values than there are columns, you need to explicitly specify the columns you are inserting to. For example

```
INSERT INTO test(firstcolumn,secondcolumn) VALUES(1,2);
```

Those columns that are not specified will get the default value, or NULL if there is no default value.